# HttpURLConnection does not work on Android

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, bufferedinputstream

I have a problem and really do not know what is wrong :-/

I have a simple function called after button click

```
public void clickFunc(View view) {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://google.com");

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.connect();
            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    result.append(line);
                }
                in.close();
                httpTxt.setText(result.toString());

            }
            else {
                httpTxt.setText("false : "+responseCode);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            httpTxt.setText("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }


    }
```

But after a click my output is Exception: null

In manifest I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

This code is by my opinion same as all codes mentioned here or at internet :-/

httptxt is my texview for output from the page

Thank you

Comment: This may throw a android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Comment: I am getting HTTP status code 411 for this code. Does www.google.com accept POST requests? The code works fine if i use GET instead of POST. What do yoy want to achieve through this code?

Comment: It seems then Google server is denying your requests then.  HTTP Status Code 411 (Length Required) is sent by the server as a response when it refuses to accept a message without a content-length header, for whatever reason.

Comment: I changed it to GET and then to http://stackoverflow.com, but result is still the same :-/ I wanna contact php script with a code and get back some result - like get.php?code=888 - this script should generate some answer like 333 and this code I would like to show in phone :)

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Where an exception occurs? Do you call it from background thread?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I did not know I have to do it in the background... it is working now,thank you!

```
public void clickFunc(View view) {

        new SendPostRequest().execute();
    }
    private class SendPostRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground (Void... params) {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        BufferedReader reader;

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com"); 

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.connect();
            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    result.append(line);
                }
                in.close();
                return(result.toString());

            }
            else {
                return("false : "+responseCode);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            httpTxt.setText(s);
        }

    }
```

I am not an android programmer, so even if its basic I did not know that, sorry guys :)

About my app if you are interested why I wanted it - I read a barcode, go to the php script, look into the database if there is this code and return true or false

Answer (score 0):

There are many threads on android, When are you hit an http request this mean it will work with another Thread,So if do you want to hit an http request you have to put  it under async class because it's a long operation, and finally if do you want to change by http response 
you have to put your changes inside UI thread which mean it should be under `Handler` or `RunOnUiThread` because Async task can't have access to UI thread directly
if you don't want to use Asynctask and runUiThred neither handler 
 use  [volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) it's google's API allowing